# Is it correct to say "some rain"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sentence-meaning

It is the onset of rainy season in this part of the world.
It happened I reported in a Whatsapp page that "Some rain in ABC place."
Is the usage of the "some" + "rain" correct in English?

Comment: I think it's alright to quantify uncountable nouns (like rain) with "some". "Some" in this context would mean "a little". Similarly, we can say, some bread, some water, some space etc.

Comment: It was good enough for Henry Wadsworth Longfellow http://www.hwlongfellow.org/poems_poem.php?pid=39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use "some rain" in a sentence. Rain is *uncountable* and *some* can be used with uncountable nouns.

I am giving some examples from a vocabulary site.

1 We did **get some rain** yesterday afternoon.

2 We had a couple warm days last week and **some rain**.

3 Of course, into every life **some rain** must fall.

4 **Some rain** falls in winter – but not much.

[reference](http://word-in-sentence.com/search-results-some-rain/)